# javafx - Several stages with a same owner

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to create a seven stage so that six of them were always on top of the seventh (main window and instrument panels). If I set first stage as owner for others, they retain the sequence in which they were created, and when you click on the stage, it doesn't go to the top level. Can you tell how to do it?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main");

    Stage s1 = new Stage();
    s1.initOwner(primaryStage);
    s1.setTitle("first");

    Stage s2 = new Stage();
    s2.initOwner(primaryStage);
    s2.setTitle("second");

    Stage s3 = new Stage();
    s3.initOwner(primaryStage);
    s3.setTitle("third");

    s1.show();
    s2.show();
    s3.show();
}
```

(Stage with title 'first' in focus but not on top)

[image: stage]

Comment: Provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Works just fine with 8u40 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Seems to specific to Mac. Can reproduce with  `1.8.0_25` on Mac.

Comment: Works fine with 8u45 on Windows, anyway you can give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377516/javafx-make-any-other-stages-close-when-the-main-stage-is-closed-yet-allow-th/30387363#30387363